# Start thread with parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameter-passing, abort

I need to abort a thread if the code takes more than 3 seconds to execute. I am using the below method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    if (RunWithTimeout(LongRunningOperation, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000))) {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker thread finished.");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker thread was aborted.");
    }
 }

public static bool RunWithTimeout(ThreadStart threadStart, TimeSpan timeout) {
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(threadStart);
    workerThread.Start();

    bool finished = workerThread.Join(timeout);
    if (!finished)
    workerThread.Abort();

    return finished;
}

public static void LongRunningOperation() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Can you please tell how can I do the same thing for the function having parameters. For example:

```
public static Double LongRunningOperation(int a,int b) {
}
```

Comment: This might give you a clue?
 Thread Constructor (ParameterizedThreadStart) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx

Comment: A side note: Thread.Abort() is considered unsafe, it could destabilize or deadlock your app. Depending on what LongRunningOperation() is executing.

Answer (score 0):

See [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

If you are using .Net>=4.0 You can also use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx/)

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>LongRunningOperation(a,b));
```

**--EDIT--**

Per your edit(answer)

Change your code as below

```
if (RunWithTimeout(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LongRunningOperation), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000)))
```

and

```
public static void LongRunningOperation(object ao){.....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that'll contain the 2 int parameters and then use [ParametrizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) and pass in your object