# How can I use async to increase WinForms performance?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tesseract

i was doing some processor heavy task and every time i start executing that command my winform freezes than i cant even move it around until the task is completed. i used the same procedure from microsoft but nothing seem to be changed.

my working environment is visual studio 2012 with .net 4.5

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<string> task = OCRengine();          
    rtTextArea.Text = await task;
}

private async Task<string> OCRengine()
{
    using (TesseractEngine tess = new TesseractEngine(
           "tessdata", "dic", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
    {
        Page p = tess.Process(Pix.LoadFromFile(files[0]));
        return p.GetText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not yet familiar with what await does. I suggest you read some basic introductions. Await does not schedule threads, for example.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, you're still doing all the work *on the UI thread*. Using `async` isn't going to automatically offload the work onto different threads. You could do this though:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string file = files[0];
    Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => ProcessFile(file));       
    rtTextArea.Text = await task;
}

private string ProcessFile(string file)
{
    using (TesseractEngine tess = new TesseractEngine("tessdata", "dic", 
                                                      EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
    {
        Page p = tess.Process(Pix.LoadFromFile(file));
        return p.GetText();
    }
}
```

The use of `Task.Run` will mean that `ProcessFile` (the heavy piece of work) is executed on a different thread.

Comment: +1. One more link with detailed explanation of the similar sample - http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/01/performance-tips.aspx

Comment: shouldn't this line `Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => ProcessFile(file));` be like this: `Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => return ProcessFile(file));`?

Comment: @Prokurors: Nope. Expression-bodied lambda expressions don't have return statements.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But what about this way: `Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => {return ProcessFile(file);});`? Compiler accepts this way too, but what is the difference between these two?

Comment: @Prokurors: Basically no difference in this case. They're both lambda expressions with the same result. You can't convert a statement-bodied lambda into an expression tree, that's all - irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by starting your task in new thread.
Just use Thread.Start or Thread. ParameterizedThreadStart

See these for your reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx

[Start thread with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465076/start-thread-with-parameters)

Comment: Tasks are the newer way of doing this. They are much more flexible and intuitive to use than Threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *BackgroundWorker* component.