# UI still freezing when using async/await

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I'm no expert in terms of asychronous operations and hoping that someone can help me point out the problem.

In one of my methods I have written a wrapper,

```
public static async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryRawSQLAsync(string sqlStatement)
{
    int _returnValue = -1;
    using (SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            _comm.Connection = _conn;
            _comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
            _comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // other codes on setting parameter

            try
            {
                await _conn.OpenAsync();
                _returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(await _comm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    return _returnValue;
}
```

in my UI, I call the method like this,

```
int _recordsAffected = await MyClass.ExecuteNonQueryRawSQLAsync("INSERT....");
```

To test if it's really working, i tried to supply an invalid database server address in the connection string so it keeps on searching until it throws an exception.

While the program is still connecting, the UI freezes. What are the things that are missing in my wrapper? or are there any other needed initializations that I need to do?

Comment: The method that you call the `ExecuteNonQueryRawSQLAsync` in - is that `async`?

Comment: @ChrisMantle it is the name of my wrapper. Inside the wrapper, is an async method `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From bitter memory, TCP sockets have a very similar issue - basically, the name resolution is performed synchronously, even for the async operations. There are two ways around this:

- use an IP address instead of a name
- make sure you start the `Open*` / `Connect*` / whatever *from a worker thread* - perhaps `Task.StartNew`

Untested, but presumably:

```
await Task.StartNew(_conn.Open);
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for this marc? or you found it by experience?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I haven't looked; basically, I found this the hard way by hitting a very similar issue - IIRC I then peeked in reflector

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The problem is not actually with sockets (which have a fully asynchronous Win32 API), but with Microsoft's wrappers. The problem for HTTP connections is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx), and I believe that Marc is correct that this same problem exists for SQL connections as well.

Comment: @StephenCleary Am aware of the `HTTP` does some synchronous work to initiate an async operation. but can't find any resource for Sql and sockets as well

Comment: +1, though I encourage the use of `TaskRun` over `Task.Factory.StartNew` (explained [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)).

Comment: @StephenCleary [is this what you mean about `TaskRun`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14963064/491243)? sorry but i didn't understand all of this. Both of you and Marc says that I need to rewrite my `ExecuteNonQueryRawSQLAsync` wrapper?

Comment: @Rossana: My previous comment has a link to my blog where I explain why I don't recommend `StartNew`. I recommend you change your wrapper the way Marc suggested but using `Run` instead of `Factory.StartNew`.

Comment: @StephenCleary if you don't mind, can you please help me rewrite the code? this is my first time writing C# codes :(

Comment: @StephenCleary is this what you mean? `await Task.Run(() => _conn.Open());`

Comment: @Rossana: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @StephenCleary let me check where i messed up because basically when I rewrite the code, the UI still freezes when I stop my Sql Server instance.

Comment: @StephenCleary OMG it works, in some part of the code ia have this line, `_varList = await _repo.GetAsync(_schoolYear, _schoolterm, _courseCode);` but when i changed it to `_varList = await Task.Run(() => _repo.GetAsync(_schoolYear, _schoolterm, _courseCode));` but I have still question, why is `_varList = await _repo.GetAsync(..,..,..);` not enough? inside `GetAsync` called my `ExecuteNonQueryRawSQLAsync()` wrapper. is msdn's `.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` not working?

Comment: @Rossana: It's the same problem that Marc described in his answer. To summarize, a lot of .NET network calls are not *actually* asynchronous.

Comment: @StephenCleary that perhaps is unfair; perhaps more reasonably: they are not *quite* as asynchronous *as they could be*

Answer (score 0):

await "somemethod" doesn't mean that the method is called asynchronosly. You are still doing a regular method call that will run like any other until the method being called decides to return a task *representing* an asynchronous operation, which you then await.

If the method does a bunch of time consuming stuff before returning the awaitable task, you can call it using [TaskFactory.Startnew()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx).

Comment: so how is my answer different with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19029317/2816021

Comment: @Rossana Notice that the post says "Correctly written methods". If the method blocks while CREATING the task, it is not "correctly written". Asynch methods should return right away. If the creation of a task is time consuming (it needs resolve DNS naming or something), the creation itself should be wrapped in a new task so that the client considers the whole thing to be just one awaitable task.