# Run EF6 Query in separate Thread on WinForm Button Click Event

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, entity-framework

I am very new to both Entity Framework AND multi-threading and finding it a bit confusing how to not lock up my winforms UI while making a large EF query.

So, suppose I want to, on a button click, query my database and return a large dataset while not locking up the UI and being able to send messages to my user that the query is in progress, I don't know how to do this AT ALL, but am trying!!

I tried to (obviously incorrectly) implement Jon Skeet's advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14963064/1693085), and so I've created the following code, but I'm getting errors and know I'm doing it wrong. I just don't understand how to do it right... PLEASE any links / advice / sample code would be **VERY* much appreciated!!

**My current code (giving errors):**

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Dim y As New List(Of DB_Data)

    Val1 = "Val1"
    Val2 = "Val2"

    Dim qry As task = Task.Run(Function() GetDBInfo(Val1, Val2))
    y = Await qry
End Sub
```

**The method I want to run Asynchronously (I have no clue if this should be `Async` or not) :**

```
Private Async Function GetDBInfo(Val1 As String, Val2 As string) As Task(Of List(Of DB_Data))

    Dim retval As List(Of DB_Data)

    Using x As New DB_Context
        retval = Await (From rw In x.DB_Data
                         Where rw.Val1 = Val1 And
                               rw.Val2 = Val2
                         Select rw).ToListAsync
    End Using

    Return retval
End Function
```

---

Again, as I said, this is not working and could be **dead** wrong - I just don't know any better how to do it right... Any help would be greatly appreciated! - And even though this is in VB, I'm equally comfortable with VB / C# solutions.

Thanks!!

Comment: In your button click event - try and just call `GetDBInfo(Val1, Val2)`. It should still return a Task that you can await

Comment: @JensKloster, you're right it does, but that seems to keep it on the same thread as my UI and blocks it from user interaction... the `Task.Run()` seemed to create a new thread for it, no??

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but you don't need the `Task.Run` method with EF 6. EF 6 comes with `real` async methods such as [ToListAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx). These methods are using new ADO.NET's async methods behind the scene and they don't consume or create any threads at all. `Task.Run` is designed to call CPU-bound methods, [more here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html). Also it starts a task on the thread pool to do the calculations, [more here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). But `real` async methods do not use any threads at all, [more here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). So just using

```
var result = await (from b in db.Blogs orderby b.Name select b).ToListAsync()
```

is enough to free the GUI thread. Also don't use blocking methods and properties here such as wait or result, [more info](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: That's what I tried originally (before I saw Jon Skeet's answer) and it tied up my UI thread... I just got confused with how to use this without tying up the thread....